The tenant for tenant guid does not exist. Microsoft Graph API with Nodejs
I want to read email messages from a given email account dynamically, but I encountered the error message: "The tenant for tenant guid does not exist". How can I resolve this issue?
error message
"error": {
   "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
   "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '24f192b9-85d3-4710-859a-d0806xxxxxxx' does not exist.",
   "innerError": {
   "oAuthEventOperationId": "8de2a75d-8df8-4a92-935e-660d3a102c5f",
   "oAuthEventcV": "X3bGiYtMYExtlEcJ5dVwWg.1.1",
    "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
        "requestId": "042ee1f5-40d0-4936-ae12-79b9bb7bcf23",
        "date": "2024-12-19T08:56:58"
       }
   }

auth.js
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-node";

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    authority: process.env.AAD_ENDPOINT + "/" + process.env.TENANT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
};

const tokenRequest = {
  scopes: [process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + "/.default"],
};

const apiConfig = {
  uri: process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + "/v1.0/users",
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

/**
 * Acquires token with client credentials.
 * @param {object} tokenRequest
 */
async function getToken(tokenRequest) {
  return await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
}

export default {
  apiConfig: apiConfig,
  tokenRequest: tokenRequest,
  getToken: getToken,
};


read email code
export default router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const token = await emailAuth.getToken(emailAuth.tokenRequest);
    // console.log(token);

    const url = `${emailAuth.apiConfig.uri}/${email}/messages`;
    const accessToken = token.accessToken;
    // console.log(url);
    // console.log(token.accessToken);

    let data = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });

    data = await data.json();
    console.log(data);

    return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS, data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
  }
});

Have done the App registration with Azure
Here are my API permissions

Authentication

Need to read the email messages from the user given email id eg: test@outlook.com

To resolve the error, you need to switch to user interactive flow to read the mails of personal Outlook account and call call /me/messages endpoint

As outlook is a personal Microsoft account it will not work with acquireTokenByClientCredential flow

For the endpoint /me/messages gives the same error and if it does not work with acquireTokenByClientCredential then what should be the flow?

Yes /me/messages do not work with acquireTokenByClientCredential use any user interactive flow like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=nodejs

Or refer https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/request.md


Note that: You need to make use of delegated flow or user interactive flow to fetch the mails of personal Outlook account and generate access token. Also make use of /me/messages endpoint.

Register Microsoft Entra ID application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)":

Make sure to grant Mail.Read or Mail.ReadWrite permission of Delegated type:

Use this GitHub sample to generate the access token.
Add redirect URL as http://localhost:3000/redirect under Mobile and desktop applications platform:

Also, enable Allow public client flows to "Yes" and Save:

Generate the access token:
Make sure to pass scope as Mail.read
app.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
    // You can also build the tokenRequest object directly in the JavaScript file like this
    const tokenRequest = {
        // The URL from the redirect will contain the Auth Code in the query parameters
        code: req.query.code,
        scopes: ["Mail.read"],
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/redirect",
    };

    // Pass the tokenRequest object with the Auth Code, scopes and redirectUri to acquireTokenByCode API
    clientApplication.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
        console.log("\nResponse: \n:", response);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

Now use the above token and call me/messages endpoint:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages


Reference:
microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/lib/msal-node/docs/request.md at dev · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

InteractionRequiredAuthError: invalid_grant: AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.

What is the redirect url you are using?

http://localhost:3000/redirect is a redirect url

after the the successful authentication if I hit the /redirect api then get the
  "errorMessage": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: 85d6b32e-ade2-4ad8-8e74-f2b5e86a8300 Correlation ID: 50f91f98-faa4-4b68-9529-cf5c4f06314e Timestamp: 2024-12-21 15:13:48Z",

Okay sure will check and reproduce the sample and I will update you:)

In redirect url query I get code, client_info and session_state and I pass the only code in tokenRequest object then it says AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented. why?

The error is bcx you have enabled the public client flows and when enabled you should not pass the client secret

For the ‘ConfidentialClientApplication’ flow client secret is required. Is i need to follow ‘PublicClientApplication, flow?

Yes you are right

That woks but if I go with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages API it says
"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid '24f192b9-85d3-4710-859a-d080627c1bfe' does not exist.

I've verified the access token's tenant ID, and it matches the one in App Registration

Pass common as tenant Id in the code

Kudos to Rukmini :)

Once after including the offline_access scope in the code and API permissions, why can't I get the refreshToken

What is the scope you are passing ?

Scope must be https://graph.microdoft.com\.default offline_access

And msal automatically handles expiration of token no need to perform anything
